# how can I code counting animation with comma in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, counter

I made counting animations! But, the Designer asked them to take commas every three digits, so I wrote a code to take commas, but I think it should be uploaded in real-time, not just at the end. I'm not used to JavaScript yet. ㅜㅜ How should I fix it?

```js
function counterAnimationHandler() {
  const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter ')
  counters.forEach(counter => {
    counter.innerText = '0' //set default counter value

    const updateCounter = () => {
      const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target') //define increase couter to it's data-target
      const count = +counter.innerText //define increase couter on innerText

      const increment = target / 200 // define increment as counter increase value / speed

      if (count < target) {
        counter.innerText = `${Math.ceil(count + increment)}`;
        setTimeout(updateCounter, 1);
      } else {
        counter.innerText = numberWithCommas(target); //if default value is bigger that date-target, show data-target
      }
    }

    updateCounter() //call the function event
  })

  function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
  }
}

counterAnimationHandler();
```

```html
<div class="counter" data-target="1000000"></div>
```

Comment: Fix what exactly? What's not working as intended? `it should be uploaded` Nothing in this code uploads anything, what am I missing?

Comment: Seems like you should do `counter.innerText = numberWithCommas(Math.ceil(count + increment))` in the `if` part. Or probably even better, keep the current value it in a separate variable, so you don't run into parsing issues caused by the parsing that happens at `const count = +counter.innerText`. In other words, better not use the innerText value for parsing, store current value in a variable so no parsing will be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you keepp a different variable for `count` with the raw (unformatted) number and then make sure you wrap every update to the UI with `numberWithCommas`.

```js
function counterAnimationHandler() {
  const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter ')
  counters.forEach(counter => {
    counter.innerText = '0' //set default counter value
    counter.dataset.count = 0;
    const updateCounter = () => {
      const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target') //define increase couter to it's data-target
      const count = +counter.dataset.count //define increase couter on innerText

      const increment = target / 200 // define increment as counter increase value / speed

      if (count < target) {
        const newCount = Math.ceil(count + increment);
        counter.dataset.count = newCount;
        counter.innerText = numberWithCommas(newCount);
        setTimeout(updateCounter, 1);
      } else {
        counter.innerText = numberWithCommas(target); //if default value is bigger that date-target, show data-target
      }
    }

    updateCounter() //call the function event
  })

  function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
  }
}

counterAnimationHandler();
```

```html
<div class="counter" data-target="1000000"></div>
```

Comment: Even better: use `Intl.NumberFormat()` to format the numbers instead of using regex to add the thousands separator :) e.g. `return x.toLocaleString('en-US', { useGrouping: true })`

Comment: @Terry a good suggestion, I hope the OP sees.